# LCD not displaying any character with I2C or when used separately

Tags: arduino-uno, i2c

I have an arduino uno and pin connection for I2C are -

```
SDA --> A4
SCL --> A5 
VCC --> 5v
GND --> GND
```

This the code i am uploading taken from the examples -

```
#include <Wire.h> 
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>

// Set the LCD address to 0x27 for a 16 chars and 2 line display
LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x27, 16, 2);

void setup()
{
    // initialize the LCD
    lcd.begin();

    // Turn on the blacklight and print a message.
    lcd.backlight();
    lcd.print("Hello, world!");
}

void loop()
{
    // Do nothing here...
}
```

The LCD shows nothing after upload . I have tried adjusting the potentiometer on I2C; just the blank characters come up.

Comment: This looks correct. You could try `lcd.setCursor(0, 0)` before the print. Is the backlight coming on as expected?

Comment: There is also a chance that the display is having a different address than`0x27`; see this answer: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/28508/53450

Comment: Running the I2C scanner sketch (https://playground.arduino.cc/Main/I2cScanner) would be the first thing to do to check if the I2C is detected on the bus and with which address.

Comment: Use the I2C scanner sketch to verify the I2C address of the display. I also have a non-standard LCD that has different pin mappings between the I2C module and the LCD itself, and I had to use a version of the LiquidCrystal_I2C constructor that let me specify the pin assignments.

Comment: Thank you all i found the problem, some of the pins were not properly soldered and had to use **LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x27, 20, 4)**

Comment: Which LCD display model are you using? There are quite a few variations.

Comment: #Duncan using 2 x 16 display with I2C serial board. I am having another major issue if you guys could help.Go to **https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/62587/esp-01-responding-to-some-codes-not-all-like-of-adafruit-mqtt?noredirect=1#comment134355_62587**